How to call the number of element in one "direction/axis" of an array?
For the following function $f: \mathbb R^F \to \mathbb R$, namely
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^N \left\lVert \nabla_x^n g(x) - \nabla_x^n h(x) \right\rVert
$$
I need to calculate the $n$-th derivative of the functions $g: \mathbb R^F \to \mathbb R$ and $h: \mathbb R^F \to \mathbb R$. $\nabla_x^n g(x)$ and $\nabla_x^n h(x)$ denote arrays with the respective higher-order partial derivatives. For example, for $n=1$ these are $F$-tuples, for $n=2$ these are $F \times F$-matrices and so on. Those higher-order derivatives arrays have the shape of $F \times F \times F ...$. In the above function I define the norm as the square root of the sum of all squared elements of the array $\nabla_x^n g(x) - \nabla_x^n h(x)$.
In my terminology, I use the word "shape" to denote, for example $F \times F$. Also, I use the word "dimension" like in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension: The dimension of a space is the number of free variables to specify a point in that space.
I am aware that the word "dimension" can have different meanings. For example, in https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dimension#English it becomes apparent that "dimension" in the context of a vector space is a singular property. In contrast, for a ball described in physics, "length" and "weight" are individual dimensions, while the space of such balls has the singular dimension of 2. I already use the word "dimension" in the former sense and thus cannot use it in the latter in order to avoid confusion in my text.
Due to the way $g$ and $h$ are build, their partial derivative arrays can contain a lot of fixed zeros and thus, their respective space does not have dimension $F \cdot F \cdot ...$, but a lot lower.
To illustrate with matrices: If a have the space of $N \times M$ upper triangular matrices ($N\ge M$), then this space has the dimension of $\frac{M^2+M}{2}$. (The matrix gets padded with zeros below the value-filled area.) I can call the "$N\times M$" the "shape of the matrices". But what are  $M$ and $N$ called? Some authors would call them the dimensions of the matrix, but this would clash with my definition of "...number of free variables..."; in that sense the matrix does not have dimension or dimensions. One could say that I have two indices, but I think, this makes the matrix an "array of order two" or a "second-order array" and this does not refer to the values of $M$ and $N$ themselves (only that I do not need a third capital letter to describe the shape of the matrix). This triangular matrix above was just to illustrate the distinction between "dimension" as in "free variables", in contrast to colloquial "the array has has three dimensions" in computer science. In fact, I am working with arrays of higher order than matrices, so I cannot talk about "rows" and "columns" anymore.
Even though arrays can be used to describe tensors, tensors are not arrays, but multilinear maps. This is similar to as tuples are not vectors, but some vectors, e.g., Euclidean vectors can be described using tuples. (When I say vector, I mean it in the general sense as of a general vector space, not the particular Euclidean vector space.) In the way the partial derivatives are used in $f$ they are not used as tensors, but simply as partial derivative arrays.
To get to the question: How should I call the $F$ in the case of $f$ in the beginning of the text, or the $M$ and $N$ with the triangular matrix example? Also, how can I call the "direction"/"axis"/"dimensions" of the arrays?
As I explained, "dimension" is already defined in my text differently.
